# remote bash script execution

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am thinking about a bash script that can login to 10 servers one by one, execute some task and save the output in a common file in the source server from which I am logging into the servers. To be more clear, I am using a test server 'test'and I need to login to other servers such as server1,server2,...server10 using ssh. Once I logged in successfully, execute some command, say cat /root/serverstatus and save the output to a common file in the 'test' server in a file named serverstatus.txt. I have ssh keygen is already installed and no password is required to enter to these servers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ssh` is your friend. `ssh remote 'string of script commands to execute'` > yourfile.log. Look at `man ssh` and it will describe the capability. If you have a script on the remote you want to execute, then `ssh remote '/path/to/script'` > yourfile.log.

Answer (score 0):

From test server

```
for i in {1..10}; do ssh server${i} cat /root/serverstatus; done > file
```

If your user isn't root add sudo before cat
For some operation with sudo via ssh you should comment line "Defaults    requiretty" in sudoers file